# Calculate Volume m3?

Tags: geometry, volume, cubics

I'm attempting to calculate the value that is m3 but i don't know how the person got these values.

[image]

The first row first column is 22mm(width) x 100mm(height) .. then the bold in the second column is 2.7metres(length).  How does the person get the m3 value?

ppp stands for pieces per pack.

I converted the length to mm, so i did 22mm x 100mm x 2700mm and the 5940000 and this is wher ei get stuck.

Comment: Hard to guess because for the volume of a cuboid we'd calculate $0.022\times 0.100\times 2.7=0.00594$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you want cubic meters, not cubic millimeters, so instead of converting the length to millimeters, you should convert the width and height to meters. That gives you: $$0.022\text{ m}\times0.100\text{ m}\times2.7\text{ m}=0.00594\text{ m}^3$$ This is the volume for *one* piece. Multiplying this by the number of pieces per pack gives $2.57202\text{ m}^3,$ which yields $2.572$ by rounding.